# alert when counter reach specific time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this jquery Count up (http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2012/09/count-up-jquery/) and i am trying to make an alert when the counter reach 00:01:05:40 (one hour - 5 minutes and 40 seconds) i am not an expert and so far i tried the code bellow:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var mytime = $('#countdown').html();
if (mytime == "00:01:05:40"){
alert ('Done');
}
});
</script>
```

Source code: http://tutorialzine.com/2012/09/count-up-jquery/

Thanks

Comment: you need to add a loop around your code, because it's only rone once.

Comment: 1: The code is run only once. 2: Have you checked the value of `var mytime = $('#countdown').html();` Do you get the content of `#countdown` in the format you are expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do it with:

```
$(function(){
   setInterval(function(){
      var mytime = $('#countdown').text().replace(/\s+/g, '');
      if (mytime == "00010540"){
        alert ('Done');
      }
   },1000);
}
```

this will run your function every half second to see if it matches the time you want.

Comment: Setting the interval function to half a second adds unnecessary stress to performance in this case. When you watch a clock hand go round you dont count twice a second each time the large hand goes round. Your answer works but i would set the interval to 1000 ms or 1 second.

Answer (score 3):

### Your problem

Using `$('#countdown').html()` will return all the HTML within the `#countdown` element. If your own version is anything like the demo you've linked to, this will return:

```
<span class="countDays"><span class="position">                 <span class="digit static" style="top: 0px; opacity: 1;">0</span>               </span>             <span class="position">                 <span class="digit static" style="top: 0px; opacity: 1;">0</span>               </span></span><span class="countDiv countDiv0"></span><span class="countHours"><span class="position">                  <span class="digit static" style="top: 0px; opacity: 1;">0</span>               </span>             <span class="position">                 <span class="digit static" style="top: 0px; opacity: 1;">0</span>               </span></span><span class="countDiv countDiv1"></span><span class="countMinutes"><span class="position">                    <span class="digit static" style="top: 0px; opacity: 1;">0</span>               </span>             <span class="position">                 <span class="digit static" style="top: 0px; opacity: 1;">0</span>               </span></span><span class="countDiv countDiv2"></span><span class="countSeconds"><span class="position">                    <span class="digit static" style="top: 0px; opacity: 1;">1</span>               </span>             <span class="position">                 <span class="digit static" style="top: 0px; opacity: 1;">7</span>               </span></span>
```

### Pulling the numbers

If you want to return the numbers, you can instead pull the `text()`. This will initially give you:

"                   0                                                   0                                   0                                                   0                                   0                                                   2                                   1                                                   2               "

We can then call `replace()` to remove those spaces and return a string like:

```
$('#countdown').text().replace(/\s+/g, '');
-> "00000212"
```

We can then use this instead:

```
var mytime = $('#countdown').text().replace(/\s+/g, '');
if (mytime == "00010540")
    ...
```

### Checking periodically

The further problem with your code is that you only run that check once. As the `#countdown` element changes every second, we can add a timer which checks this value every second:

```
setInterval(function() {
    // Your function here
    var mytime = $('#countdown').text().replace(/\s+/g, '');
    if (mytime == "00010540")
        ...
}, 1000);
```

Here, `1000` is 1000 milliseconds, which is equal to 1 second.

Comment: `$('#countdown').text().replace(/\s+/g, '')` to just trim all white space.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#countdown').html()` will return all html elements.
Try using `.text()` , this will return text only.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
       setInterval(function() 
       {
          var mytime = $('#countdown').text();
          if (mytime == "00:01:05:40")
          {
              alert ('Done');
          }
       }, 1000);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: What is updating the `#countdown` text?